# At what point does number theory stop playing with finite rings?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview, ra.rings-and-algebras

Basic results in number theory, like the Chinese remainder theorem, the Euclidean algorithm and Euler's theorem, are really about finite structures, namely the rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for suitable $n$, or perhaps other finite rings (such as quotients of extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$). Such results can be treated without a worry by a [finitist](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+mathematics). It is ingredients like this that are sufficient for, say, implementation of the RSA encryption scheme. However, at some point number theoretic results became statements (much more powerful and interesting statements!) about things like [rings of adeles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring).

My question could be taken two ways:

> What are the most powerful results in number theory which one can state and prove using the machinery of finite rings?

or

> At what point in time did number theory move from considering finite rings to more analytic objects, and by what time was this move 'complete'?

For a reference post, one can point to the [Lasker–Noether theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasker%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) (1921), which can be taken to be a statement about finitistic objects (and ignoring the possibility that infinite objects exist), namely finite modules $M$ for a ring $R$ (possibly infinite, in which case one could think of it as a finite ring by quotienting by the kernel of $R\to End(M)$).

My motivation for asking about this question is not to be controversial or obtuse, but to get an idea about how far a finitist might get in proving theorems in number theory. Much as [reverse mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) finds the precise strength of a subsystem of [second-order arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic) that is necessary to prove an analytic result (for example, the intermediate value theorem, the Heine–Borel theorem or the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem), one could try to see how strong theorems in classical number theory are. This of course is something far outside the scope of a single MO question.

Comment: The infinitude of primes is a pretty basic part of number theory that was found quite early in its development, so I don't understand what you mean by "at what point in time" did number theory not consider finite rings, because non-finite aspects have been around since the beginning. 

Comment: Dear David, Much about the adeles is actually finitistic; for example the Chinese remainder theorem, and the pigeon hole principle, are at the basis of many basic statements about the adeles; the adeles just provide a convenient way to encode the relevant information.  My own view (or perhaps it is more of a hope/faith) is that most, even all, of the number theory that I am interested in is finitistic at its core.  Cheers, Matthew 

Comment: I think the main interest in using infinitary methods is that the proofs can be much shorter. In other words, the use infinitary methods can be motivated for purely practical reasons. See my answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61632/what-is-the-high-concept-explanation-on-why-real-numbers-are-useful-in-number-the/61677#61677

Comment: @KConrad - this is true, but let's pretend my fictional finitist has a grasped the concept of potential and completed infinity, in the sense that any list of primes can be extended by one, but no complete list of primes could be postulated to exist. 

Comment: Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes does not use infinitary methods at all. It's a bit confounding because it is a negative statement: "infinite" = "not finite". The usual proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational (= "not rational") has the same character but clearly does not use infinitary methods. See also this great post by Andrej Bauer on negative statements and their proofs - http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/

Comment: What Euclid actually proves is that for every finite list of primes there is a prime not on the list. That is a positive statement. 

Comment: @Aaron: You're (almost) right! "Prime numbers are more than any assigned multitude of prime numbers." (Elements, Book IX, Proposition 20)

Comment: @françois: I'm not saying that there is NOT a difference, but where do you see it? "Finite" is implicit. a list is ordered and a multitude perhaps not but that seems minor. Is it the word "assigned" or the fact that there is not a privileged "next" prime?

Comment: Dear David, I find your question potentially very interesting, but right now, too ill-formulated to have a satisfying answer.
First there are two questions, that you present as essentially the same, but that looks completely different to me. One is about when number theory stopped being finitist, the other is when number theory began using analytic tools. Both are not exactly well-defined, but
they are very different. Let me focus on the first one, which is the one I find more interesting. The problem is in the definition of finitist. If one uses a too restrictive definition, then number..


Comment: ...theory was never finitist, since from the beginning, as KConrad points out, people were aware of the infinitude of primes, and even before, of the infinitude of integers. One should observe that Francois's argument that Euclid's statement and proof of the infinitude of prime number is actually finitist is not true, strictly speaking, as finitists do not in general accept formula about integers which bound variables, and the statement "for every $n$, there exists a prime $p>n$" is therefore not finitist. It is clear that in this question, "finitist" should be interpreted in a more...

Comment: liberal way... Bot how ? I would find it helpful if you clarify your position about this point. Many thanks.


Comment: @Aaron: I said you're right! The quote was to support your claim. The parenthetical almost was because you didn't *exactly* quote the Elements.

Comment: @Joël: I didn't claim that Euclid was finitist, only that the proof didn't use infinitary methods. However, to the best of my knowledge even strict finitist accept the existence of objects that can be constructed from integers in a finite number of steps. Anything less than that should probably be called ultrafinitist. (Of course, it's pointless to discuss this since there are probably more variants of finitism than there are finitists!)

Comment: For some people, "for every $n$, there exists a prime $p > n$" could be problematic because the $p$ is *un*bounded.  But we can actually prove "for every $n$, there exists a prime $p$, $n < p < n!$".  So anybody who accepts factorials (ultrafinitists might not) should be happy with this statement about constructing one number from another.

Comment: Surely, if you can accept that there is a prime $n \lt p \lt n!$ you also need to accept that there is a prime $n \lt p$?! The proof provides an explicit way to find $p$ given $n$ in finitely many steps. What more could a finitist want? (I do see where ultrafinitists might have issues.)

Comment: Sorry, my comment is not well stated.  I mean that it might be impossible (in some finitist framework) to establish that some $p$ exists without simultaneously establishing an upper bound.  But we do have that bound.  So it ought to be possible to write the proof in an acceptable way.

Comment: @François - I presume because there is no uniform bound on the size of $p$ given $n$. Knowing that we have a computable function $f(n)$ (with $f(n) \gt n$) such that there is a prime in the finite list $n+1,n+2,\ldots,f(n)$ means that only a finite search is needed. Otherwise we need to pick an element out of an infinite set $n+1,n+2,\ldots$ (or however one wants to interpret a tail of a sequence). @Toby - shouldn't that be $n \lt p \le n!+1$? Although if our finitist accepts Bertrand's postulate (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate), we can take $f(n) = 2n$.

Comment: @Joël I think that my hypothetical position is that proving things about finite finite objects is ok (including finitely generated modules over finite rings), and that there is a class of natural numbers. Likewise there are rational numbers, but the field of rational numbers should be thought of as a Field (capital F!) and so usual operations cannot be performed with it. However, anything using analysis is out, as are objects like the absolute Galois group of some generic number field, although one could argue that working with the Galois group of some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is ok. 

Comment: As long as we are letting the comments flow freely, I don't see that the infinitude of the primes is any more involved (in some sense) then that of the integers. "Integers are more than any assigned multitude of integers" Proof: Add them all plus 1, the whole is greater than the parts.

Comment: @Aaron: I was just about to make that point: Isn't every number has a successor a finitistic fact?

Answer (score 10):

Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions, proved in 1837,
 needing real-analytic methods could possibly be the first major candidate for a
 number-theoretic result departing from finite methods. (This was proved 50 years earlier than Prime Number Theorem).

Comment: For an unusually large value of 50. 

Comment: Although there is an elementary proof by Selberg: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969454, which doesn't seem to use more than quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: ...and finite sums of logarithms.

Comment: +1, this is at least a plausible answer to the first part of the second question.

Comment: I believe Euler's use of divergence of the harmonic series to prove the infinitude of primes predates this. 

Comment: This does not really qualify, because Euler re-proved an older result. But didn't he get more results from his proof than Euclid's theorem?

Comment: Dirichlet did not have complex analysis at his disposal - all his arguments were real. Euler gave heuristic arguments suggesting that the sum of the reciprocal primes p less than x grow as log log x. 


Comment: I agree that this is a good bound, but as later non-analytic proofs were found, it weakens the argument somewhat.

Comment: @ Benjamin Sternberg & Franz Lemmermeyer:  Yes, the very term 'Euler product' connecting (real) zeta function with an infinite product running over primes  suggests analysis in number theory had entered before Dirichlet. (So my reputation points can be brought down for the  inaccurate answer I gave earlier).

But we see mostly Riemann's name (as opposed to Euler) as showing the connection between distribution of prime numbers and  Zeta function. Would be happy to get clarified on this point by the community here .

Comment: Dear P, Perhaps you could correct your answer to replace "complex analytic'' by "real analytic'', following Franz's (correct) comment. Regards, Matthew 